# How to extract data from DWH on a certain date? Is there the special pattern for this case in Postgres SQL?

Tags: postgresql

Usually we use EXTRACT (FROM YEAR date_column) = 2000 (let it be 2000 year). Also we can add EXTRACT (MONTH FROM date_column) = 1 (let it be January). Also we can extract a day - EXTRACT (DAY FROM date_column) = 5 (let it 5). But is it possible to use the pattern for this data? How does it look like in Postgres SQL

Say we have the table Shipment, the columns - date_payment, quantity, sum.
I'd like to get the table that content all shipments for 01.01.2020
How to query this table with data format 'YYYY-MM-DD', not using EXTRACT-function?

Comment: You will need to provide an example of what you want the final data to look like. Add as update to question. On a hunch do you want something like: `select to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD'); 2022-05-13`. As the function name implies this will be a string. For more information see [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Adrian Klaver, I've done the corrections)

Comment: Is the `date` column a `date` type or a `timestamp(tz)` type?

Answer (score 0):

If the date column is a `date` type then:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date_col = '2020-01-01';
```

If the column is `timestamp` or `timestamptz` then:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date_trunc('day', date_col) = '2020-01-01'
```

Beware that with `timestamptz` time zones come into play when doing the `date_trunc`. From here [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC):

> When the input value is of type timestamp with time zone, the truncation is performed with respect to a particular time zone; for example, truncation to day produces a value that is midnight in that zone. By default, truncation is done with respect to the current TimeZone setting, but the optional time_zone argument can be provided to specify a different time zone. The time zone name can be specified in any of the ways described in Section 8.5.3.

For a `timestamp` value per the above link:

> A time zone cannot be specified when processing timestamp without time zone or interval inputs. These are always taken at face value.